# QGIS 3.4.4 crashing when adding hyperlink into the Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv, hyperlink

I made a CSV with coordinates and hyperlink connected to JPG photo.
I uploaded it into QGIS, export it as  ESRI shapefile, and uploaded back it into QGIS.

I want to display the photo with hyperlink. I set the layer Attributes From properties as follow: **Widget Type:** Attachment, **Storage Mode:** File paths, **Display button to open file dialog** marked, **Use hyperlink for document (read-only)** marked and **Integrated Document Viewer** Type: Image.

[image]

When I use the "Identified features" button I see the hyperlink, when I click it the JPEG is opened with Dropbox.

[image]

However when I am trying to add anther hyperlink to the shapefile from the Attribute Table  , the QGIS is crashing (the log at the end).

[image]

So, I have two questions:

1) How can I prevent QGIS crushing when adding hyperlink to the Attribute Table?

2) How to set the layer to display the photo, not the hyperlink?

***Log:***

‎

```
2019-02-15T14:52:01     WARNING    warning:C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-‎packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: 
‎              
‎             Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: ‎https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings 
‎              
‎              
‎             traceback: File "", line 1, in  
‎              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 344, in startPlugin 
‎              plugins[packageName].initGui() 
‎              File ‎‎"C:/Users/nitza/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\quick_map_services‎\quick_map_services.py", line 121, in initGui 
‎              self.init_server_panel() 
‎              File ‎‎"C:/Users/nitza/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\quick_map_services‎\quick_map_services.py", line 311, in init_server_panel 
‎              self.server_toolbox = QmsServiceToolbox(self.iface) 
‎              File ‎‎"C:/Users/nitza/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\quick_map_services‎\qms_service_toolbox.py", line 155, in __init__ 
‎              self.show_news() 
‎              File ‎‎"C:/Users/nitza/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\quick_map_services‎\qms_service_toolbox.py", line 160, in show_news 
‎              qms_news = client.get_news() 
‎              File ‎‎"C:/Users/nitza/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\quick_map_services‎\qms_external_api_python\api\api_abstract.py", line 64, in get_news 
‎              response = get(url, verify=False) 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in ‎get 
‎              return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs) 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in ‎request 
‎              return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs) 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line ‎‎512, in request 
‎              resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line ‎‎622, in send 
‎              r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line ‎‎445, in send 
‎              timeout=timeout 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", ‎line 600, in urlopen 
‎              chunked=chunked) 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", ‎line 343, in _make_request 
‎              self._validate_conn(conn) 
‎              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", ‎line 857, in _validate_conn 
‎              InsecureRequestWarning) 
‎             ‎
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002687/4699904

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.

Comment: Here is the link to the bug report  https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21333

Comment: @NitzanMatan See this bug report also https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19118